# In Desktop application how to create popup progress bar

Tags: c#, windows

I work on C# .I want to create a Desktop(not web) application in c#.There i need to popup window like as web.When popup window appear user can not access any control like web loading panel property **MODEL=true**.My application work flow is:

```
Popup appear
 Event Start
  Event Complete
     Popup close
 Then Perform rest of the application

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
if (progressBar1.Value >= 200)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = 0;
                GetAllData();//When this Method active .Progress bar show it's //progressing.After complete the work progressbar will hide.How can i measure how much //time does the computer needs to complete this method work.
                timer1.Stop();
            }
            progressBar1.Value += 20;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your popup is a form you can use `ShowDialog` instead of `Show` to make the form modal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talkin about modal dialog boxes. If you using WPF, read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx